# Change ListView SelectionMode Template

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, uwp-xaml

i would like to change the template of the checkbox that is shown wenn having SelectionMode=Multiple on a ListView in UWP. I don't want a checkbox, but a custom UI. My Application changes from SelectionMode=None to SelectionMode=Multiple and back, I would like to keep the sliding animation. 
My List shows items with amounts, and on select I want to select the amount, not a checkbox. The image should visualize my idea:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2gbM.png)
Do I need to create this by hand by binding to Visibility? How to create the "sliding" animation in that case?

Regards,
user3650130

Answer (score 0):

I will edit the answer to make it complete later. Currently I will share the direction first.

Actually you can find generic.xaml from (Program Files)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\\Generic folder
Where you will see ListviewItem sytle with x:key="ListViewItemExpanded",this file will be used later.

And in your code say if you have a listview, you can put the above style in your itemcontainerstyle, something like:

```
 <ListView  SelectionMode="Multiple">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
                <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local" />
                <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,0,12,0" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinWidth}" />
                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinHeight}" />
                <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="False" />
                <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}" />
                <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ComboBox Grid.Column="0">
                                    <x:String>1</x:String>
                                    <x:String>2</x:String>
                                </ComboBox>
                                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

        <x:String>1</x:String>
        <x:String>2</x:String>
        <x:String>3</x:String>
        <x:String>4</x:String>
        <x:String>5</x:String>
        <x:String>6</x:String>
    </ListView>
```

You will find that you can only see your content, right? The actual problem here is related to ***MultiSelectSquare***, a border which a fonticon in the style, it controls the behavior of checkbox here. We need to delete it and put combox there. But it will cause exception since some transform/animation's target is this border. We need to modify it to make it works. You can start from this direction first.

---

I modified my above code and add the following line in control template:

```
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ComboBox Grid.Column="0">
                                <x:String>1</x:String>
                                <x:String>2</x:String>
                            </ComboBox>
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1"/>
                        </Grid>
```

As you can see, if you add this, you will see both your content and your combobox. But still, as I've mentioned, if we just do this we will miss the features and animations, we also need to modify the visual state based on the default style.

---

OK. So now you understand that what is the key point. Then we need to go thought the default template, please search the ListViewItemExpanded resource from generic.xaml. Notice the border which is called "MultiSelectSquare"? There are four things which is related to the animations: "MultiSelectSquare" "MultiSelectClipTransform" "MultiSelectCheckBoxTransform" "MultiSelectCheck". A simple demo is like, replace the FontIcon to Combobox but keep MultiSelectCheck as the name of Combobox. Then delete any animation in visualstategroup about MultiSelectCheck. You will see although it's a checkbox showing, when you click it, it is actually popup a combox.

But for the complex demo, you have to write your own animation yourself for each state.

Comment: Thank you for your help; with your solution I see only my content when selected. I assume I have to use the ContentPresenter to display my ComboBox, right? I have never used it before.

Comment: @user3650130 Sorry for confusing. I put contentpresenter here is only for testing purpose. Contentpresenter is used to display the binding content, and when you check the default style, you find that there is a border called MultiSelectSquare, this is actually when checkbox is located. To make you understand the code,let me modify it with a simple demo.

Comment: I confirm that I see the combobox and the content. Both at the same time, changing SelectionMode does not change anything. No animation or change. What should be the next step now?

Comment: @user3650130 I've made an edit for your direction. In general, you may have to rewrite the whole animation yourself to make it works correctly.